# Import tables from Access into SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a lot of tables in Microsoft Access 2010, and I tried to import all these tables into SQL 2010, I want to know how can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+%5Bsql-server%5D+import

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution would be by creating a SSIS package that does the import

Answer (score 0):

Import using DTS

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/ms-access-to-sql-database/